# New Drupal User wants to limit the height of a node, say inside of book pages: how to?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am working on a new site that I want all pages to break when the content reachs 540 px, and it would be nice to be able to make that so with just certain node types like pages/books. I can't figure out how to do. The site is here: 
http://202.52.231.58/ 
and you can see what I've done with UNITION vs. UNITION (test) pages. One is a book in 5 parts, which I had to chunk myself, and then add paras to try and get the book pages the same depth. But this is a ridiculous way to do, no? There must be some programatic way to say: if book page reaches 500 px in height, break to a new page? Or at minimum, a way to say: for any book page, make the height 500 px regardless of content. Hope that's clear. Any help appreciated!
Jigs

Answer (score 0):

Would the paging module solve your problem?

http://drupal.org/project/paging